# Using variables in header script

Tags: php, header

I want to pass some information to another page using "header" but I also want to use a variable for the location, for example:

With a static URL in location:

```
header("Location: mypage.com?fname=$_POST['fname']&lname=$_POST['lname']");
```

I want to use a variable like so:

```
header("Location: $myVariable?fname=$_POST['fname']&lname=$_POST['lname']");
```

But I can't for the life of me get the syntax right, as shown above it will throw an error, any help is appreciated.

Tom

Comment: please show the error you're getting

Comment: can't pass by reference and/or headers already sent? or undefined indexes? no idea what you're asking here

Comment: you have answers below, ask them. I won't "guess" this. bye bye

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set a full url (with `http://`) and use put arrays between parentheses `{}`.

Working well with a static url:

```
header("Location: http://mypage.com?fname={$_POST['fname']}&lname={$_POST['lname']}");
```

Working well with a url variable:

```
$url = 'http://mypage.com';
header("Location: $url?fname={$_POST['fname']}&lname={$_POST['lname']}");
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: Just what I wanted, Thank you Allan. Worked like a charm.

Answer (score -1):

There are two way you can achive this, one is use session and another this url strucutre, 
In session :

```
session_start(); // this should be on top of login_check file
// this goes just before redirect line
$_SESSION['fname'] = $_POST['fname'];
```

Or use url structure as follows,

```
header(wwww.example.com?action='')
```